# getProjectByName(projectname) throwing null pointer exception in groovy when running through command line

Tags: groovy, command-line, soapui, test-runner

I am trying to automate some test cases and in my groovy script I am getting null pointer exception on getProjectByName(projectname).
When I am running it in SOAP UI it is working but when running through command line it is giving null pointer exception.

I have searched for it a lot but couldn't find something working.
Any help will be very grateful.

Here is my code that is in groovy script:

```
groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
projectname = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.name
workspace = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace
project = (workspace==null) ? ProjectFactoryRegistry.getProjectFactory(WsdlProjectFactory.WSDL_TYPE).createNew(groovyUtils.projectPath +"\\"+projectname+".xml") : workspace.getProjectByName(projectname)
wsdlProject = workspace.getProjectByName(projectname)
```

I am getting exception on:

```
wsdlProject = workspace.getProjectByName(projectname)
```

Later I want to run testSuites of the same project and I want to run project from command line.

For running testSuites I am using:

```
wsdlTestSuite = wsdlProject.getTestSuiteByName(TestSuite Name)
runner = wsdlTestSuite.run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the project. But you are already using...

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace
```

...to get the workspace, which the project is a part of. Going THROUGH the project variable itself to get it.

Couldn't you just change the last line to

```
wsdlProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It did the job (y).